# Threaded comments with LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

I have try load comments with json and load more function, but problem is because don't know how to make properly query,

```
"SELECT comments.*, 
    (SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE users.record_num = comments.userid) as avatar 
FROM comments 
WHERE content = '$id' AND approved='1' 
ORDER BY comments.rating DESC 
LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

If i call this query without LIMIT all is displayed properly, but when i call it with LIMIT than problems is come, problem is example if LIMIT is 3 per page i get as result

```
comment 1
--comment 2 replied to comment 1
--comment 3 replied to comment 1
```

but should be

```
comment 1
--comment 2 replied to comment 1
--comment 3 replied to comment 1
comment 2
--comment 7 replied to comment 2
--comment 8 replied to comment 2
comment 6
--comment 10 replied to comment 6
```

So parent comment should't be counted in some way, but also i need to get parent id from database.

Comment: It's difficult to help you without sample data to go along with your expected output, as well as what those PHP variables contain that you incorporate into your SQL.

Comment: How about a two-step process? First, fetch ids of top level comments (you apply the limit here). Then, after you have your 3 commens, you hydrate the comment trees with another query.

Comment: @Martin It's content numbers only, `content` is id of post, `parent` is id of comment

Comment: @uLike: How do you differentiate whether any record in the comments table is a main comment or reply to a comment? Also, you want to print all replies or want to apply a limit on it as well?

Comment: 'parent' default is 0 so no reply to main comment, if `parent` is >0 than this number is ID of main comment.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev yes this maybe can help me but new query should be called after every comment and check if there is parent?

Comment: @uLike: no, not necessarily, you can fill them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have following table structure:

**comments**

```
id,
post_id,
user_id,
comment,
parent,
approved,
rating
```

**users**

```
record_num (which will be same as comments.user_id)
```

Now if you run the following query then it will list desired numbers (`$max_results`) of main comments (where `parent is 0`) but will list all its replies (where `parent > 0`) for each main comment. In order to manage it easily on front-end, I've converted the replies part into a JSON so iterating main result-set will print main comments (which will be only 3 in your case) but inside it, if you iterate `replies` column/index then it will list all replies for current main comment without any limit.

```
SELECT 
    c.*, 
    IF( (u.avatar != '' and u.avatar IS NOT NULL), u.avatar, 'no-image') as avatar,
    CONCAT( '[', GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('{"id": "', c1.id, '", "reply": "', c1.comment, '"}') SEPARATOR ',' ), ']') AS replies

FROM comments AS c

LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.userid = u.record_num

LEFT JOIN comments AS c1 ON c.id = c1.parent

WHERE c.id = '$id' AND c.approved='1' AND c.parent = 0

GROUP BY c.id

ORDER BY comments.rating DESC 

LIMIT $from, $max_results
```

Additionally, I've changed the `avatar`, instead of getting it from a inner query, I've replaced it with a `LEFT JOIN` so if it has any image then it will return image otherwise simple string `no-image`.

Hope this will solve your problem...

Comment: Hmm seems that not work... 
Table comments

`userid => user id who posted, 
comment =>text, 
content => post id, 
timestamp => time when is posted,
approved,
parent_id,
record_num => or row id`